# How do I install Wine 3.15?

Tags: software-installation, wine

I'm trying to install the latest WINE, and I'm reading the readme, it's telling me to do the `./configure` thing but when I do I get this message

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

What am I supposed to do, and how do I fix it, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, anything newer than this runs into some problems this is an old computer.

Answer (score 4):

WineHQ has nice repositories for most Ubuntu versions.

You should install `wine` using the steps listed on [the official documentation](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) instead of compiling by source.

Since you want version 3.15, you should pick `winehq-staging`, which I use in my `xenial` installation without problems.

Basically the steps are:

```bsh
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 # if using a 64bit distribution of Ubuntu
curl -L https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging # staging repo for 3.15 version
```

In addition, maybe you would want to have also the latest version of winetricks - according to [the official documentation](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks):

```
cd "${HOME}/Downloads"
wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
chmod +x winetricks
sudo mv winetricks /usr/local/bin/
```

Then you can type `winetricks` into a terminal to run it, for the further new versions it will guide you how to update.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that your terminal is in the same directory as `./configure`, if it is not, then `bash` will simply not be able to find it. Use absolute path, i.e. `/path/to/file` or `~/path/file`, `~` is substituted by your `$HOME` directory.

[terminal opened at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2otv.png)

If the folder is messy, verify that `./configure` exists by typing `ls | grep configure`; to search subdirectories use recursive mode, `ls -R | grep configure`.

TIP: Copying file/directory from file manager and pasting it into text field (i.e. terminal, text editor, browser URL field) will produce its absolute path. To paste into terminal use shortcut `shift+ctrl+v`, middle mouse button or use context menu (right click).